# Recode different 'types' of missing in R from a .dta file

Tags: r, tidyverse, stata, missing-data

I have a Stata file (.dta) with different types of missing data (either because a question wasn't relevant for this person (`.`) or because a person didn't know the answer (`.r`). These differences matter for my analysis. I do not have access to Stata and would like to do this analysis in R. I looked at the  `{sjlabelled}`, `{labelled}`, and `{haven}` packages, but cannot find a way to recode these different types of missing data.

The Stata command `tab q2, m` gives

```
               q2 |
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |
x sorry sensitive |
      xxxxxxxxxxx |
       xxxxxxxxxx |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------------+-----------------------------------
               No |        342       14.43       14.43
              Yes |        673       28.40       42.83
                . |      1,234       52.07       94.89
               .r |        121        5.11      100.00
------------------+-----------------------------------
            Total |      2,370      100.00
```

However in R no distinction between `.` and `.r`

```
table(mydf$q2, useNA = "always")
```

gives

```
   0    1 <NA> 
 342  673 1355
```

However, R does recognise that there are different 'types' of missing (`NA` and `NA(r)`)

```
sjlabelled::tidy_labels(mydf$q2)
<labelled<double>[2370]>: q2: xxxxx?
   [1]     1     NA   NA(r)     1     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     0     0     1     1    NA     1    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA(r)    NA    NA    NA(r)    NA
```

and

```
> get_labels(mydf$q2, values = "n", drop.na = FALSE)  
               -888                   0                   1 
"Unsure/Don’t Know"                "No"               "Yes"
```

How can I relabel the `Unsure/Don’t Know` category to a variable instead of a missing, while keeping the other missings actually missing?

### Update

per request also the `str()` output

```
> str(mydf$q2)
 dbl+lbl      1,     1,    NA,     1,    NA,     0,    NA,    NA,    NA,     0,    NA,    NA,     1,    NA, NA(r),    NA,    NA,    NA, NA(r),    NA,    NA
 @ label       : chr "xxxx?"
 @ format.stata: chr "%19.0g"
 @ labels      : Named num [1:3] -888 0 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Unsure/Don’t Know" "No" "Yes"
```

### data

here is a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ddIZ8__xzPpBODGXaIiCejJBXeJ_fKbk/view) to a small dataset that has the same data structure

Comment: It looks like the variable is imported as numeric, is that so? Please post the result of the `str(mydf$q2)`

Comment: No, I dont think it is imported as numeric. at least using both `as.numeric()` and `to_numeric()` simply return `NA` for the `NA(r)` values and not `-888` (as I had hoped)

Comment: I think you need to convert the values to factors using `as.factor(mydf$q2)`, but you should read the intro vignette from `vignette(package="sjlabelled")` to confirm that does what you want.

Comment: I tried that,  but for that also just makes both types of missing into a normal R `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, there is the best way to solve your problem, but I  thought of a way to create a variable in R where you can see the different types of missing values. This variable could guide your data analysis later.

1. You can add a label of your missings in Stata, for example, using your data set I wrote:

```
use test_data.dta, clear 
gen index = "" 
replace index = "no missing" if !missing(s2)
replace index = "missing value type 1" if s2 == .r
replace index = "missing value type 2" if s2 == .
save test_data_labeled.dta, replace
```

```
2. In R you can import your data with the labels. Later, you can generate a new variable (s2_mod in this case) as a character that considers all the possible values of your missings. 


# Import data and packages 
rm(list = ls())

library(pacman)

p_load(rio, 
       here, 
       tidyverse, 
       magrittr)

df <- import(here("datos", "test_data_labeled.dta"))

#  Recode your variables according the missing values type 
df <- df %>%
        mutate(mv1 = ".r", mv2 =".")

df2 <- df %>% 
  transmute( s2 = as.character(s2), 
             s2_mod = case_when(
                      index == "missing value type 1"  ~ mv1,      
                      index == "missing value type 2" ~ mv2))  

 df2$s2_mod[is.na(df2$s2_mod)]  <- df2$s2[!is.na(df2$s2)]
```

In this case, the variable s2_mod is a character with all the original values considering "r" and ".".

Comment: Yes of course, if I had access to Stata this would not be a problem at all. But in the actual use case I will have to run the analysis on a server without access to Stata ().